# url for getintent in watson assistance returns Resource not found

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Please help I am unable to consume this API service for getting Intent using the source code below,

```
var assistant = new watson.AssistantV1({
    username: '********',
    password: '******',
    url:'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1 /workspaces/{workspaceid}  /message?version=2018-09-20',
    version: '2018-02-16'});

assistant.getIntent({
   intent: "Hello",
   workspace_id: '******'}, function(err, response){
   if(err){
      console.error(err);
   }else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
   }
});
```

The return error message is

```
Error: Resource not found
code: 404,
error: 'Resource not found',
'x-global-transaction-id': 'ffea405d5c4ef5012b3fd98b'
```

Comment: Please format and make it actual code. If it is, watch spaces in the URI...

Comment: What country is your Assistant hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just that trivial, but the URI has illegal spaces? Have you tried this?

```
url:'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/{workspaceid}/message?version=2018-09-20'
```

Comment: Do your credentials include username / password or IAM token?

Comment: username and password

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SDK, then your `url` value should point to the API version only.

For example:

```
url:'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1'
```

If it is still the same error, then you need to ensure you are using the right end point for where your Watson Assistant is hosted.

Latest details here: https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant#service-endpoint

Summary:

- Dallas: https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api
- Washington, DC: https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api
- Frankfurt: https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api
- Sydney: https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api
- Tokyo: https://gateway-tok.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api
- London: https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of errors in your small snippet of code as @Simon O'Doherty and @data_henrik have pointed out. It looks like you are coding in Node.js so this reference to the API documentation will help.

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant?language=node#get-intent

In summary

1. You have the URL wrong
2. I am guessing that you are using a new instance of Assistant, in which case your credentials will be an IAM Key rather than a username / password credentials
3. If you are running `getIntent` then you need to provide the identifier for the Intent that you are retrieving, is this really 'Hello' or is that a copy from somewhere else? If you run `listIntents` that will provide you with an indication of its real identifier.